# Run both of "DROP DATABASE" and "CREAT DATABASE" in CLI with "-c" option of psql of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transaction, scripting, command-line

When debugging programs, I need to frequently drop a database of Postgresql, and then re-create it again.

To convenient, I want to execute this in a single command line like following:

```
psql -c "DROP DATABASE my_db; CREATE DATABASE my_db;"
```

But I get a error:

> ERROR:  DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Is there a way I can do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-c` option repeatedly:

```bash
psql -c 'DROP DATABASE my_db' -c 'CREATE DATABASE my_db'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!